# SUM.PRODUCT - how to get an array of values that correspond to a single cell value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to calculate weight average per user for three different processes. My table looks like this:

```
User       || Process   || Bonus[%] || Weight
John Smith || RETURNS   || 5        || 2
John Smith || PUTAWAY   || 10       || 3
John Smith || RECEIVING || 7        || 1
```

So basically I want my formula in each row to look like this:

`=SUM.PRODUCT({5,10,7},{2,3,1})/SUM({2,3,1})`

The formula needs to have an array of values based on the User Name. How can I do that?

Comment: I think you need to provide a better sample of data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2=$A$2:$A$7)*($C$2:$C$7)*($D$2:$D$7))/SUMPRODUCT((A2=$A$2:$A$7)*($D$2:$D$7))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(user_name_column="user name"),[Bonus %],[Weight])/SUMIF(user_name_column,"user name",[Weight])
```

adjusting the ranges to match your data locations.